# Creating new branch in gitlab UI; reality does not look like documentation

Tags: user-interface, branch, gitlab

I'm new to gitlab, though I have some experience with git.  The recipe for creating a new branch in gitlab from the UI says

> If you want to make changes to several files before creating a new
>   merge request, you can create a new branch up front. From a project's
>   files page, choose New branch from the dropdown.

(https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/repository/web_editor.html#create-a-new-branch)

The problem is that my page simply does not have the dropdown as shown in the example on the site.  Everything else looks the same, but I have no access to any dropdown.  I have developer access to the project.  Is the documentation outdated and I need some other method?  Does it sound like there is a problem with the gitlab installation I have to use here?  Any ideas are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a self hosted instance of GitLab if so what version are you using? go to /help to find the version.
It is possible you are using an old version of GitLab and this feature isn't available.

Comment: No.  Not self hosted.  Adds another layer of difficulty.  Thanks for the idea.

Comment: If it's not self hosted and its hosted on gitlab they'll have the latest version. According to the permissions page https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/permissions.html developer access should be able to create a new branch.